# Use a LINQ Query to return a list of of items from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

I am looking to write a very simple LINQ query to list items from my database. Here is what my model looks like:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
  {
    public UsersContext()
      : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Membership> Membership { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

  }

  [Table("UserProfile")]
  public class UserProfile
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
  }

  [Table("webpages_Roles")]
  public class Role
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is my Controller:

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
 {

  public ActionResult UserList(string username)
  {
    using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
    {
        var username = UserProfile.UserNames.ToList()
     ;
        return View(username)
    }

  }
```

Can someone please just tell me how this query is supposed to work. I really use want to be able to list all of the UserNames on a View in a list format

View:

```
  @model IEnumerable<Comtrex_ICU.Models.UserProfile>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserTable";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2 class="admin-home-link orange-titles">@Html.ActionLink("User 
Information", "AdminIndex")</h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

        <p></p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the UserList view too?

Comment: Shouldn't it be it be `db.UserProfile.UserNames.ToList()`?

Comment: Try `var usernames = db.UserProfiles.ToList();` and model should be `UserProfile`

Comment: @WaelAbbas that worked! This is the code I used:    public ActionResult UserList(string UserName)
      {
        using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
        {
            var model = db.UserProfiles.ToList();
            return View(model); 
        }
      }

Comment: I think answering these questions is bad, I suggest to go back to basic before going any further, a good place to start would be [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx), try not to just make it work, try to learn, in case it is binding the model to the view try reviewing .net mvc basics.

Answer (score 1):

`db.UserProfiles` will return all rows in `UserProfiles` table

So you can try `var userProfiles = db.UserProfiles.ToList();` to get list on this rows, and model should be `@model IEnumerable<Comtrex_ICU.Models.UserProfile>`

Comment: Thank you! I also adding a link to display the email address of the user. Do you know how to do a <a href=mailto"(modelItem => item.Email)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</a> attr so that when someone clicks they can send an email from outlook?

Comment: @MeganMeluskey I think you miss `:` email link should look like `<a href="mailto:@(item.Email)">Link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AccountController : Controller
 {

  public ActionResult UserList(string username)
  {
    using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
    {
        var username = db.UserProfiles.Select(x => x.UserName ).ToList();
        return View(username)
    }    

  }
```

Comment: im getting an erro that says Models.UerContext does not contain a defination for UserProfile

Comment: @MeganMeluskey I believe it should be `UserProfiles`, to match your property name on the `DbSet`. Though you'll also run into some issues in your view when this returns strings, and it's looking for `Comtrex_ICU.Models.UserContext`s. But this is a step.

Comment: Please don't post just code. Add some explanation/comments to help OP understand your answer

Comment: That works better but now I am getting this error message The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Comtrex_ICU.Models.UserProfile]'.

Comment: Can you please try this changes: `var username = db.UserProfiles.Select(x => x.UserName ).ToList().AsEnumerable();`